# How to exclude door sweep from bounding box using revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, bim

I have a revit file in which there are a few doors. When i try to extract the bounding box of the door then the sweep of the door is also included in the bounding box which i dont want. I just want the bounding box corresponding to the door itself. I am very new to revitAPI and C#. I would really appreciate if you guys can write some piece of code which can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Door sweeps are typically not shown in 3D. Have you considered asking for the 3D bounding box instead of the current view? (Pass a null into the BoundingBox/get_BoundingBox method).

Comment: Yes passing null will give the bounding box without sweep but there can be other hardware attached to the door which we don't want in the bounding box such as handle and stuff. Basically i just want the width of the panel of the gate without any other accessory .

Comment: I think at that point you would be scanning the geometry of the door and looking for “large” face geometry and deciding whether to include or exclude each face in the envelope. But that’s more arbitrary/heuristic to decide.